# Let $f$ and $f'$ both be integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'(t)\mathrm dt=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Where $\mathrm dt$ in 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'(t)\mathrm dt=0
$$
denotes Lebesgue integration.

My first instinct was to use the difference quotient form of the derivative 
$$
f'(t)=\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}+o(|h|)
$$
but the little o term poses problems in integrating over $\mathbb{R}$.

I am also concerned about using the FTC as $f'$ needn't be continuous, but I think the FTC holds almost everywhere? I also considered potentially proving that $f$ is uniformly continuous, possibly using the fact that the tails of the integral of $f'$ can be made arbitrarily small, thus ruling out the annoying tall narrow triangles function which is integrable and doesn't vanish at $\pm \infty$. However, I am having difficulties working out the details and would appreciate any hints!

edit: All I am given is that $f$ is differentiable and the integrability conditions.

Comment: Assuming that $f$ is absolutely continuous: Suppose $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(t)\,dt = c \neq 0$. Estimate $$\int_{x < \lvert t\rvert < y} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt = \int_x^y \lvert f(t)\rvert + \lvert f(-t)\rvert\,dt \geqslant \int_x^y \lvert f(t) - f(-t)\rvert\,dt$$ for large $x$ and $y$.

Comment: If $f$ isn't absolutely continuous, and $f'$ denotes the classical derivative where it exists (which should be almost everywhere to make the assertion not obviously wrong), then it need not hold. Let $f$ climb from $0$ to $1$ on $[0,1]$ per the Cantor function and then descend back to $0$ linearly on $[1,2]$. Then $f'(t) = 0$ almost everywhere outside $[1,2]$, and hence $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(t)\,dt = \int_1^2 f'(t)\,dt = -1$.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere? Make this clear please.

Comment: @zhw. edited to be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has to be careful.  Consider:

$$ f(x) = \cases{0 & if $x \le 0$ or $x > 1$\cr
                 x & if $0 < x \le 1$\cr}$$
$$ f'(x) = \cases{0 & if $x < 0$ or $x > 1$\cr
                  1 & if $0 < x < 1$\cr
           \text{undefined} & if $x = 0$ or $x = 1$\cr} $$
Then $f$ and $f'$ are Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$, but $\int_{\mathbb R} f'(x)\; dx = 1$.

EDIT: On the other hand, it is true that if $f$ is differentiable **everywhere** and $f' \in L^1[a,b]$, then $$f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x)\; dx$$
See e.g. Rudin, "Real and Complex Analysis", Theorem 8.21.

Comment: @qbert, There are non-constant continuous functions $f$ which is differentiable a.e. with $f' = 0$. The Cantor function (which is also mentioned in Daniel Fischer's comment) is an archetypal example.

Comment: @SangchulLee this would seem fine? I am confused why continuity is not enough to use the FTC

Comment: So assuming I can use the FTC, this problem seems to reduce to proving $f$ vanishes at $\pm\infty$, which again I think requires uniform continuity

Comment: You don't need to use that $f$ vanishes at $\infty$. All you need is that there exist sequences $y_n \to +\infty$ and $x_n \to - \infty$ such that $f(x_n) \to 0$ and $f(y_n) \to 0$. This follows from the integrability of $f$. Then $\int_{x_n}^{y_n} f' \to 0$, and so by the fact that $f'$ is integrable and the dominated convergence theorem, $\int_\mathbb R f' = 0$. Note that everywhere differentiability is not required here, only that the FTC holds.

Comment: ... but to get that FTC, you either need absolute continuity or everywhere differentiability.